# Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an alarm discord bot using python. No errors are happening, but also no output from the bot past the try, except function

**Please note: alarm, not timer**

```
@client.command(aliases = ["alarm"])
async def alarm_at(ctx, time):
    alarm = False
    if alarm == False:
        alarm = True
        now = datetime.now()
        mtimeA = time
        mtimeB = mtimeA.split(":")
        hr = int(mtimeB[0])
        min = int(mtimeB[1])
        secsleft = int((timedelta(hours=24) - (now - now.replace(hour=hr, minute=min, second=0, microsecond=0))).total_seconds() % (24 * 3600))
        print(secsleft)
        await ctx.send(f"OK\Alarm go off at {time}")

        def check(message):
            return message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() == "cancel alarm"
        try:
            await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=time)
            await ctx.send("alarm cancelled")
        except:
            if secsleft == 0:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.guild.default_role} alarm finished")
    elif alarm == True:
        await ctx.send("Please cancel the current alarm to run a new alarm")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is happening in the try ... except, you won't see anything. Try this instead:

```py
        try:
            await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=time)
            await ctx.send("alarm cancelled")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            if secsleft == 0:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.guild.default_role} alarm finished")
```

Comment: " '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' " here is the error